# Resistor equivalent for RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Hi there!
I stumbled upon this circuit, and I have a hard time trying to understand if the Req for the following circuit is in series or parallel. I have tried with parallel but does not look too good. Am I on the right path? My final goal would be to calculate the time constant for the capacitor if that helps.

Comment: There are two cases, switch open and switch closed.

Comment: I forgot to mention, switch closed

Comment: Can  you simplify the circuit in some way?

Comment: I can see that the 2 resistors might be in series? Therefore yes, I guess. I am bit confused. If I remove the capacitor definito the req is in parallel, but the capacitor in the middle it's confusing me.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Req for the circuit"?

Comment: When you calculate the time constant shouldn't need to take into consideration all the resistors that affect the charge or discharge of the capacitor? Or is it R1 for charge and R2 for discharge?

Comment: @djg Assuming the capacitor is discharged to start, when the switch is first closed some current will flow in both R1 and R2. R2 because it is connected directly across the voltage supply. R1 because the voltage across C1 is 0 so the supply voltage must appear across R1, to start. But as C1 charges up (gains a voltage difference across it) the remaining voltage across R1 diminishes towards 0. Does R2 affect R1 during this process? In contrast when the switch opens up with C1 charged up, C1 then discharges through both R1 and R2. Would that be a different time constant?

Answer (score 7):

When the switch is closed, R2 is in parallel with the voltage source, so current through it and voltage across it are constant and independent of anything except that voltage source.

You are left with only R1 and C in series, with a constant voltage across that pair, and with a time constant of:

$$ \tau_{CLOSED} = CR_1 $$

When the switch opens, what remains is a closed loop consisting of R1, R2 and C. C may discharge through the combined resistance of R1 and R2, so the time constant changes to:

$$ \tau_{OPEN} = C(R_1+R_2)$$

Answer (score 4):

R2 will not affect the charge time for the capacitor. It will have a time constant of R1 * C. When the switch is opened, the capacitor will discharge through the two resistors in series, so the time constant will be (R1+R2) * C.